# USB devices recognized, but not working. Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, usb, keyboard, dmesg

I have an Ubunutu 18.04 machine that (currently inexplicably - automatic update?) restarted over this past weekend. Upon reboot, they USB keyboard and mouse do not work. This is to say, no keystroke is shown and no lights (numlocks) turn on. I have tried multiple keyboards.

`dmesg` looks like

```
sudo dmesg | grep -iFe usb | tail -n20

[50732.262444] input: Dell Dell USB Entry Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:413C:2107.000D/input/input18
[50732.322187] hid-generic 0003:413C:2107.000D: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Dell Dell USB Entry Keyboard] on usb-0000:03:00.0-1/input0
[59359.006009] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[59418.834675] usb 1-1: new low-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[59419.015970] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=413c, idProduct=2113
[59419.015974] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[59419.015977] usb 1-1: Product: Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard
[59419.023482] input: Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:413C:2113.000E/input/input19
[59419.082807] hid-generic 0003:413C:2113.000E: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard] on usb-0000:03:00.0-1/input0
[59419.087396] input: Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:413C:2113.000F/input/input20
[59419.146696] hid-generic 0003:413C:2113.000F: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard] on usb-0000:03:00.0-1/input1
[60593.694511] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 9
```

Indicating that the USB is recognized (the last disconnect is my keyboard).

`lsblk` is like

```
$ lsblk

NAME        MAJ:MIN RM    SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0    2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/238
loop1         7:1    0   87.9M  1 loop /snap/core/5742
loop2         7:2    0   42.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/701
loop3         7:3    0     13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/139
loop4         7:4    0   34.2M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/808
loop5         7:5    0   87.9M  1 loop /snap/core/5662
loop6         7:6    0   88.2M  1 loop /snap/core/5897
loop7         7:7    0  140.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
loop8         7:8    0  140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
loop9         7:9    0    3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
loop10        7:10   0   34.6M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
loop11        7:11   0   14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/45
loop12        7:12   0     13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/124
loop13        7:13   0   14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/43
loop14        7:14   0    2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/260
sda           8:0    0   15.3T  0 disk /data
nvme0n1     259:0    0    1.8T  0 disk /databases
nvme1n1     259:1    0    1.8T  0 disk 
├─nvme1n1p1 259:2    0  776.6G  0 part /
├─nvme1n1p2 259:3    0      1K  0 part 
└─nvme1n1p5 259:4    0 1011.9G  0 part [SWAP]

$ lsusb

Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0557:2419 ATEN International Co., Ltd 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0557:7000 ATEN International Co., Ltd Hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Both Dell options at the bottom are keyboards.

I have never encountered this before and I'm not sure where to go from here. Any thoughts?

I am able to ssh into the ip address and everything appears to be working normally this way.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Numlock goes, I had the same issue and did this in the terminal.

sudo apt install numlockx
(then)
numlockx on

Can't help with the rest, sorry

Comment: Appreciate it, but I'm just using the numlock light as an indicator of keyboard functionality.